# ($\mathbb{N} , U$) doesn't have a Bolzano-Weierstrass Property

Tags: general-topology

> Let T be the topology on $\mathbb{N}$ given by for each n $\in \mathbb{N}$ , $B_n= ${$2n-1, 2n$}. B'= {$B_n: n\in \mathbb{N}$} is a base for topology T on $\mathbb{N}$ and let U  be the discrete topology on $\mathbb{N}$. (a) Prove that $(\mathbb{N} ,U)$ doesn't have Bolzano-Weierstrass property.(b) Define  f: $(\mathbb{N}, T) \to (\mathbb{N},U)$  by $f(n)=\frac{(n+1)}{2}$ if $n$ is odd and $f(n) = \frac{n}{2}$ if $n$ is even. Then show that f is continuous.

I am unable to  prove any of the parts.

Attempt: (a) Bolzano-Weierstrass property means that "Every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence" and I have to find a sequence which doesn't have this property. I considered these sequences : $(1,1,\ldots), (1,1,2,2,3,3,\ldots)$ but as all sets are open in $U$ so $\{1\}$ is open and $\{1,2,3,4,\ldots\}$ is also open. So, I am unable to find such a set.

(b) In b) $\{\frac{n+1}{2}\}$ is open in $U$ but it's inverse image $n$ is not open in $T$. So, I don't think f is continuous. Can you please tell what mistake I am making?

Comment: It is not Weirestrauss, it is Weierstrass.

Comment: What is a "bounded" sequence in a general space? I think $X$ has the B-W property iff every sequence in it has a convergent subsequence (this property is usually called sequential compactness).

Comment: @HennoBrandsma You are right. I think this definition can be only be used for spaces like $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: $b)$ only defines $f$ but contains no question ...

Comment: I think they mean the property that every infinite set has a limit point. For that $\Bbb N$ with the $T$  topology is an example and $\Bbb N$ in the discrete topology does not have this property despite being its continuous image. Your text means that to be the exercise.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I have edited part (b).

Comment: What do you the inverse image of $\frac{n+1}{2}$ is? (Note that this only defined for $n$ odd).

Comment: @HennoBrandsma it is n .

Comment: No, it’s $\{2n+1,2n+2}=B_{n+1}$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Done the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence $\left( 1, 2, \cdots \right)$ has no convergent subsequence is the only convergent subsequences in the discrete topology are eventually constant ones.

As for the continuity, it is enough to check the pre-image of every set $\left\lbrace n \right\rbrace$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. If you compute it, the pre-image is $\left\lbrace 2n-1, 2n \right\rbrace$ which is a basic open set in $T$. Since any open set is a union of basic open sets, and unions are well-behaved under pre-images, $f$ is infact continuous.

Answer (score 0):

$(\Bbb N, T)$ has the Bolzano-Weierstrass property in the sense that any infinite subset has a limit point.

You can easily check that $f$ maps this space continuously onto $(\Bbb N,U)$, which does *not* have that property.

This exercise is (IMO) meant to introduce this classical counter example.